# Application written in single file fires NullPointerException

Tags: java

Can't understand, i have problem with abstract class `getOn` method, if i split my classes to different files and declare them as public, like that

```
package test.local;

abstract public class Passenger {
    public void getOn(Transport transport) {
        transport.takePassenger(Passenger.this);
    }
}

package test.local;

public class Dog extends Passenger {
}
```

everything works fine, i can pass `Passenger.this` to `getOn` method, but if i write whole application in single file like that

```
import java.util.List;

interface Transport {
    public void takePassenger(Passenger passenger);
}

class Bus implements Transport {
    private List<Passenger> passengers;

    public void takePassenger(Passenger passenger) {
        passengers.add(passenger);
    }

    public List<Passenger> getPassenger() {
        return passengers;
    }
}

abstract class Passenger {
    public void getOn(Transport transport) {
        transport.takePassenger(Passenger.this);
    }
}

class Dog extends Passenger {

}


public class Magic {
   public static void main(String []args) {
      Bus bus = new Bus();

      Dog passenger = new Dog();
      passenger.getOn(bus);
   }
}
```

i am getting *Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException*
why?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Bus.takePassenger(Magic.java:11)
at Passenger.getOn(Magic.java:21)
at Magic.main(Magic.java:35)
```

Comment: Sounds like a configuration problem. Make sure you clean your project. What line is throwing the exception? (Please post the stack trace.) Also, the first example has classes `Passenger` and `Dog` in package `test.local`, but the code that's throwing the exception seems (from what you've posted) to have those classes in the default package. That could be part of the configuration problem you're having.

Comment: Java exceptions include a stack trace. You should provide that information, or at least provide the line number of the offending line of code.

Comment: added trace, thank you

Comment: You have never initialized `passangers`. Change `private List<Passenger> passengers;` to `private List<Passenger> passengers = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: @Edwardth works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
private List<Passenger> passengers;
```

to this:

```
private List<Passenger> passengers = new ArrayList<Passenger>();
```

In the former line of code, you have not initialized `passengers` to a value so it is null. Attempting to dereference it, for example with `passengers.add(passenger)`, will yield a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize the `passengers` field in your `Bus` class. Change this declaration:

```
private List<Passenger> passengers;
```

to:

```
private List<Passenger> passengers = new ArrayList<>();
```

Moving classes around to separate files has nothing to do with the error you're reporting.

Answer (score 0):

It will always throw a NullPointerException until you initialize your list:

```
private List<Passenger> passengers;
```

to

```
private List<Passenger> passengers = new ArrayList<Passenger>();
```

Answer (score 0):

its because you have not initialized

```
private List<Passenger> passengers;
```

make a default constructor in  you Bus class like this:

```
public Bus(){
   passengers = new ArrayList<>();
}
```